# ArrayList<Integer> table in data base

Tags: java

i have this code and i want  store my table `ArrayList` in my `database`

### my code

```
public class globaleCollab {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(" les rating  :  ");
    String idoperateur = "00000006092";//operateur cible njibh m session

    sort1 sor = new sort1();
    ArrayList<Integer> table = sor.tri();
    String resultat_final = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {

        resultat_final = resultat_final + "," + table.get(i).toString();

    }

    System.out.println(table);
    System.out.println("-------" + resultat_final);
    //insrt id user, resultat_final, temps d'exe, k ,
    long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;

    System.out.println("l temps est " + elapsedTime + "ms");
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String query;
    try {


        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_recommandation", "root", "");

        query = "insert into statistic (idoperateur,id) values(?,?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, idoperateur);
         ps.setString(2, resultat_final);
        //ps.setInt(3, k);
        //ps.setLong(4, elapsedTime);
        // ps.setString(2, resultat_final);
        System.out.println("000000000000000000000000000");
        ps.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}
```

but it did not work

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: "but it did not work" - please elaborate on that.

Comment: @PM77-1 I do not know whereis the problem?? It stocks nothing in my database

Comment: What is the schema of table `statistic ` ? and by the way you should normalized your table

Comment: Can you please share the exception or stack-trace

Comment: You did not print the exception. Use this `catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }` And show us the error stacktrace

Comment: suppose you try like this [example](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) to insert the records and try because the other code seems ok.

Comment: i need how i can insert `ArrayList` in my `database`

Comment: http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the max size of the array before hand refer to: [this page of the JDBC documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html). However, if the size of the array is unknown I would recommend creating a new table where each row is an index and has one column that holds the integer.

Answer (score 0):

first: catch exception,check sql error or data error
second: ps.setString() method index from 0